# How to add email and mobile number in a single edit text?

Tags: android

Here is my editText code;

```
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userNameET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/login_email_mobile"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress|number"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

And am validating like this,

```
if (!validateEmail(userNameValue) || !validateMobile(userNameValue)) {
                return;
            }
```

I have given `inputType` as : `android:inputType="textEmailAddress|number"`.But which is always showing mobile number keyboard. But I need to access both.How can i do it?

Comment: remove number  form input type.

Comment: No need both right ? android:inputType="textEmailAddress" just this enough...

Comment: you can try setting input type programtically

Comment: You can limit the type of characters that can be inputted at run time.

Comment: Have you tried using `android:digits="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@."`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u cannot do that because keyboard will always showing the number input

So, the answer is use 2 edit text.....

Answer (score 0):

you have to set android:inputType="text" because at a time two keyboard type can not work.

Comment: But that time it wont show @ in keyboard.It will just like normal edittext na?

Comment: yes! it will be like normal keyboard, you want to do as facebook did, for that you just need to check the data present in your edit text is matched to your database or not,

Answer (score 0):

It should be Email or Mobile if you are using facebook login.
and remove **android:inputType="textEmailAddress|number"** instead use **android:inputType="text"**

Try for Email

```
boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
  return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

if your Edittext value return true than its Email or else Mobile number

Answer (score 0):

I suggest textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions as inputType. it gives you the normal keyboard with the option to display numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

**EditText**

By using digits user cannot use special characters like "#$%^*&"

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userNameET"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:digits="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@."
    android:gravity="center"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

**onClickListener**

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!checkEMailValidation(edtMobileEmail)) {
            Log.e("Validation", "Email not entered properly");
            if (!checkMobileNumberValidation(edtMobileEmail)) {
                Log.e("Validation", "Mobile number not entered properly");
            } else {
                Log.e("Validation", "Mobile number entered properly");
            }
            return;
        } else {
            Log.e("Validation", "Email entered properly");
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Methods for Email & Number Validation

```
public static boolean checkEMailValidation(EditText editText) {
    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(editText.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {
        Log.e("EMailValidation", "false");
        return false;
    } else {
        Log.e("EMailValidation", "true");
        return true;
    }
}

public static boolean checkMobileNumberValidation(EditText cellphone) {
    if (cellphone.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 10) {
        Log.e("MobileNumberValidation", "false");
        return false;
    } else {
        Log.e("MobileNumberValidation", "true");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But may be some of them will create their  with "#$%^*&"these characters too na.

Comment: Yah that's true. So you also want special characters to be entered?? If yes then just remove the `android:digits`. Also don't include the inputType attribute.

Comment: we can include inputType na...inputType as "text"

Comment: What you actually want?? Your keyboard should look like facebook login keyboard?? If you want like facebook login then include `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"` this will give you "@" on the alphabet keyboard also you can go to number keyboard